# Dynamically apply a specific function to different variables

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, eval

I have a csv that defines one row per variable (referring to real data variables that are defined in another dataset). After light massaging, I have a named vector like `fxs`.

I then can iterate over the variables, and execute the appropriate function.  Is there another way I should consider?  Perhaps with [`rlang::exec()`](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/exec.html) and/or [`purrr::map_*()`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map.html).  I like that I can wrap the two main lines with separate [`tryCatch()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/conditions.html) blocks to more accurately describe if there was an error parsing the function, or an error executing the function.

```r
fxs <- c(
  "Sepal.Length"   = "\\(x) x *   1",
  "Sepal.Width"    = "\\(x) x *  10",
  "Petal.Length"   = "\\(x) x * 100"
)

d <- iris[1:5, 1:3]
for (variable in colnames(d)) {
  fx <- base::eval(base::parse(text = fxs[[variable]]))
  d[[variable]] <- fx(d[[variable]])
}
d
```

I was thinking it looks a lot like the inside of a [`dplyr::mutate()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate.html) statement.  Maybe it's better to try to convert the csv into statements passed to `...`.  I haven't done anything beyond this proof-of-concept, so I have a lot of flexibility if someone has a different approach.

```r
d |> 
  dplyr::mutate(
    Sepal.Length   = Sepal.Length *   1,
    Sepal.Width    = Sepal.Width  *  10,
    Petal.Length   = Petal.Length * 100,
  )
```

Desired output:

```
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length
1          5.1          35          140
2          4.9          30          140
3          4.7          32          130
4          4.6          31          150
5          5.0          36          140
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may use `cur_column()` to subset the expression within `across`

```
library(dplyr)
d %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(
    dplyr::across(
      .cols = dplyr::all_of(names(fxs)), 
      .fns  = ~ eval(parse(text = fxs[[dplyr::cur_column()]]))(.x)
    )
  )
```

-output

```
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length
1          5.1          35          140
2          4.9          30          140
3          4.7          32          130
4          4.6          31          150
5          5.0          36          140
```

---

Or using `exec`

```
library(purrr)
d %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(
    dplyr::across(
      .cols = dplyr::all_of(names(fxs)), 
      .fns  = ~ rlang::exec(
        rlang::parse_expr(fxs[[dplyr::cur_column()]]), 
        .x
      )
    )
  )
```

---

If the functions are all doing the multiplication, instead create a named `vector` or `list` of values to be multiplied and avoid the `eval/parse`

```
nm1 <- c(Sepal.Length = 1, Sepal.Width = 10, Petal.Length = 100)
d %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(
    dplyr::across(
      .cols = dplyr::all_of(names(nm1)),
      .fns  = ~ nm1[dplyr::cur_column()] * .x
    )
  )
```

Comment: Your post helped be better understand `dplyr::across()`, and how different functions can be incorporated.  I hope you don't mind that I changed your formatting a little.  It helped me see the signature differences between `rlang::prase_expr()` and `base::eval()`.

Comment: @wibeasley glad to know that it helped. Thanks for the edit.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the named vector for multiplying.  I'll keep that in mind for future applications.  In the current case, the functions are like [`readr::parse_datetime()`](https://readr.tidyverse.org/reference/parse_datetime.html) and  [`readr::parse_number()`](https://readr.tidyverse.org/reference/parse_number.html)